1.3.0+L2 -> 1.4.1+L2 migration woes
i am trying to upgrade a 1.3.0+L2 safe that is tied to a circles avatar to 1.4.1+L2 I also tried a completely fresh safe. What am i doing wrong?
I enabled the migration module from 'official' contract address
safe_migration.sol: 0x526643F69b81B008F46d95CD5ced5eC0edFFDaC6
I also myself deployed the contracts from https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account and used that as a module.
This is my hardhat code:
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://rpc.gnosischain.com");
const safeAddress = "<xxx>";
const migrationModuleAddress = "0x526643F69b81B008F46d95CD5ced5eC0edFFDaC6";

const signer = new ethers.Wallet("<xxx>", provider);

async function migrateSafe() {
    const safeContract = new ethers.Contract(
        safeAddress,
        [
            "function delegateCall(address to, bytes data) external returns (bool success)",
        ],
        signer
    );

    const migrationData = new ethers.Interface([
        "function migrateL2Singleton()"
    ]).encodeFunctionData("migrateL2Singleton");

    const tx = await safeContract.delegateCall(migrationModuleAddress, migrationData, {
        gasLimit: 10000000 
    });
    await tx.wait();

    console.log("Migration complete:", tx);
}

migrateSafe().catch(console.error);



Thanks Valentin, you helped me along and it seems that operationType for delegate call in current Safe sdk version is actually 1.
"@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^5.1.0",

const migrationModuleAddress = "0x526643F69b81B008F46d95CD5ced5eC0edFFDaC6";

        const migrationData = new ethers.Interface([
            "function migrateL2Singleton()"
        ]).encodeFunctionData("migrateL2Singleton");

        // Define the transaction data with delegate call
        const txData = {
            to: migrationModuleAddress,    
            value: "0",            
            data: migrationData,        
            operation: 1, 
        };

        if(this.kit instanceof Safe) {

            const safeTransaction = await this.kit.createTransaction({ transactions :[txData] });

            try {
                const txHash = await this.kit.executeTransaction(safeTransaction);
                console.log('Transaction executed with hash:', txHash);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Transaction failed:', error);
            }
        }


this.kit = await Safe.init({
            provider: getRPC(CHAIN, alchemy_key),
            signer : this.signer_key,
            safeAddress : this.safe_address
        });



P.S. when you upgrade to 1.4.1 with official migration contract (0x526643F69b81B008F46d95CD5ced5eC0edFFDaC6) tit will not include module and fallbackhandler for account abstraction.
i added both as "0xa581c4A4DB7175302464fF3C06380BC3270b4037".

Thanks for your question.
Looking at your code, you seem to be trying to make a direct delegate call. Can you try to create a SafeTransaction with the operationType set to 2, for a delegateCall?
If this works, please mark your question as answered. I am happy to assist further.
